# Intellij freezing on activating editor

Tags: intellij-idea, freeze

My Intellij keeps freezing whenever I activate the code editor. I've restarting Intellij (13.0.2 & 13.1.2) & my system (Ubuntu 14.04) & have also tried invalidating the caches but nothing seems to help. The interesting part is that this happens only one particular file! Any ideas on how to correct this? Thanks.

Comment: Look into generated thread dumps or VisualVM sampler, or just report a bug - which you should do anyway, or do you think that it is normal?

Comment: Never seen this before. Been using it for a while now. Doesn't look normal. I'll report a bug. Thanks

Comment: Is the file huge? Is there something else odd about this file?

Comment: Not huge. It's a file I created using gedit & tried importing it as a project in Intellij. That went fine until I opened the file in the editor.

Comment: Copy pasting the contents of the file into a new file created from intellij worked

Comment: It's happening the same with me, but it's a file I'm using for quite some time without the issue. For some reason IDEA freezes for a full minute or so, have you opened the BUG at jetbrains?

Comment: No, I did not open a bug